# How can I setup video streaming via http on windows?

Tags: windows, apache, nginx, lighttpd, webm

I'm looking for a  module to one of these web servers (apache, nginx, lighthttpd) to create video streaming in webm format. My operating system is Windows.

Comment: It would be rad to get my answer accepted if it fitted your needs, otherwise a comment may help :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use VLC? It's capable of webm http streaming. Try this in your command line:

```
C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC>vlc.exe --sout "#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=300,scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=webm,dst=:8080/mountpoint.webm}" yourmovie.foo
```

You don't need to use a http server in the middle, except if you want to do some rewrite rules to keep vlc sending webm video to another port (like 8080) and then do some rewrite to make it look like it's coming from port 80.

I hope it helps.